# replace or remove the characters before @temp in containing word in complete string

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-2.7

replace or remove the characters before @temp in containing the word in the complete string

for example in output 0020_B@temp should not come

Below is the input string

This can be done either in python or in javascript.. both are acceptable

```
"{
"name": "ProcessInfo",
"children": [
    {
        "name": "0020_B|Y",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "0020_B@tempCycleTimeAdherence|Y",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "0020_B@tempTimeOfDeviation_Percentage|Y"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "0050_B|Y",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "0050_B@tempCycleTimeAdherence|Y",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "0050_B@tempTimeOfDeviation_Percentage|Y"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "0030_B|Y",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "0030_B@tempCycleTimeAdherence|Y",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "0030_B@tempTimeOfDeviation_Percentage|Y"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "0060_B|Y",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "0060_B@tempCycleTimeAdherence|Y",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "0060_B@tempTimeOfDeviation_Percentage|Y"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "0040_B|Y",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "0040_B@tempCycleTimeAdherence|Y",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "0040_B@tempTimeOfDeviation_Percentage|Y"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
   }"
```

output should be like

```
  "{
"name": "ProcessInfo",
"children": [
    {
        "name": "0020_B|Y",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "CycleTimeAdherence|Y",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "TimeOfDeviation_Percentage|Y"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "0050_B|Y",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "CycleTimeAdherence|Y",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "TimeOfDeviation_Percentage|Y"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "0030_B|Y",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "CycleTimeAdherence|Y",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "TimeOfDeviation_Percentage|Y"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "0060_B|Y",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "CycleTimeAdherence|Y",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "TimeOfDeviation_Percentage|Y"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "0040_B|Y",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "CycleTimeAdherence|Y",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "TimeOfDeviation_Percentage|Y"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
   }"
```

Comment: what is _not_acceptable is your "write some code for me" question, in any language please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this in the following way ...

**JavaScript**

- perform a search using the *regex* `[\w_]+@temp`, it'll search for any word that is followed by temp
- use [replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function to replace that word

```js
let input = `{
"name": "ProcessInfo", "children": [
    {
        "name": "0020_B|Y",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "0020_B@tempCycleTimeAdherence|Y",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "0020_B@tempTimeOfDeviation_Percentage|Y"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "0050_B|Y",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "0050_B@tempCycleTimeAdherence|Y",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "0050_B@tempTimeOfDeviation_Percentage|Y"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "0030_B|Y",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "0030_B@tempCycleTimeAdherence|Y",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "0030_B@tempTimeOfDeviation_Percentage|Y"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "0060_B|Y",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "0060_B@tempCycleTimeAdherence|Y",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "0060_B@tempTimeOfDeviation_Percentage|Y"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "0040_B|Y",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "0040_B@tempCycleTimeAdherence|Y",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "0040_B@tempTimeOfDeviation_Percentage|Y"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}`;
let output = input.replace(/[\w_]+@temp/g, '');
console.log(output);
```

**Python**

```
import re

s = """{
"name": "ProcessInfo", "children": [
    {
        "name": "0020_B|Y",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "0020_B@tempCycleTimeAdherence|Y",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "0020_B@tempTimeOfDeviation_Percentage|Y"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "0050_B|Y",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "0050_B@tempCycleTimeAdherence|Y",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "0050_B@tempTimeOfDeviation_Percentage|Y"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "0030_B|Y",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "0030_B@tempCycleTimeAdherence|Y",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "0030_B@tempTimeOfDeviation_Percentage|Y"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "0060_B|Y",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "0060_B@tempCycleTimeAdherence|Y",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "0060_B@tempTimeOfDeviation_Percentage|Y"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "0040_B|Y",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "0040_B@tempCycleTimeAdherence|Y",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "0040_B@tempTimeOfDeviation_Percentage|Y"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
"""
r = r"[\w_]+@temp"
o = re.sub(r, '', s)
print(o)
```

Answer (score 0):

So?, what's the problem then? a simple replace function should be enough

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace

Comment: Problem is... Anything can be there before @temp    . It is not fix word